# Creating two dimensional arrays in Rust

Tags: arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, rust

How do I create an empty mutable two dimensional array in Rust?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
let mut state[[u8 * 4] * 4];
```

This produces the error

```
error: expected one of `:`, `;`, `=`, or `@`, found `[`
 --> src/main.rs:2:18
  |
2 |     let mut state[[u8 * 4] * 4];
  |                  ^ expected one of `:`, `;`, `=`, or `@` here
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Editor's note: This answer predates Rust 1.0 and some of the concepts and syntax have changed. Other answers apply to Rust 1.0.

Do you want the contents of the array to be mutable or the variable that holds it? If you want mutable contents, does this work for you?

```
let state = [mut [mut 0u8, ..4], ..4];
```

If you want the variable to be mutable but not the contents, try this:

```
let mut state = [[0u8, ..4], ..4];
```

Does this help? I didn't actually compile this, so the syntax might be slightly off.

Comment: Yes. This works. Do you know how would I pass such array to the function? The function needs to change values of array. Thanks.

Comment: You could pass the value in two ways.  One option would be `&mut [[u8 * 4] * 4]`--- pointer to a two-dimensional fixed length array. You would just do `&mut state` to get such a pointer.

Comment: Oh, and normally having a mutable variable like this would also allow you to mutate the elements of a fixed-length array, as they are owned by the variable.  Unfortunately this bug <https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/3226> will prevent you for now.

Comment: @NikoMatsakis Thanks. I got it working like this & [mut [mut u8 * 4] * 4] for function parameter. How can I get pointer to first row of two dimensional array?

Comment: For future visitors: this is for a pre-1.0 version of rust, there's another answer below with an updated syntax. `let mut state = [[0u8; 4]; 4];`.

Comment: This does not work anymore, please consider removing this outdated answer

Answer (score 94):

In Rust 1.0, the following works:

```
let mut state = [[0u8; 4]; 6];
state[0][1] = 42;
```

Note that the length of the interior segment is an integral part of the type. For example, you can reference (and pass) `state` as follows:

```
let a: &[[u8; 4]] = &state;
```

but not without specifying the fixed length of the sub-array. If you need variable length sub-arrays you may need to do something like this:

```
let x: [Box<[u8]>; 3] = [
    Box::new([1, 2, 3]),
    Box::new([4]), 
    Box::new([5, 6])
];
let y: &[Box<[u8]>] = &x;
```

Comment: Note that this panics if you access out of bounds. Which doesn't feel very rust-like.

Comment: Thanks hardy, but "(and, yes, the mutability works now)" -> how would you access and mutate one element ?

Comment: @AndyHayden in the two years since your comment was posted bounds checking must have been properly implemented, as I receive compile time errors when attempting out-of-bounds access on both the outer and inner arrays.

Answer (score 29):

You can create a dynamically-sized 2D vector like this:

```
fn example(width: usize, height: usize) {
    // Base 1d array
    let mut grid_raw = vec![0; width * height];

    // Vector of 'width' elements slices
    let mut grid_base: Vec<_> = grid_raw.as_mut_slice().chunks_mut(width).collect();

    // Final 2d array `&mut [&mut [_]]`
    let grid = grid_base.as_mut_slice();

    // Accessing data
    grid[0][0] = 4;
}
```

Comment: I think it should read `...chunks_mut(height)...` assuming access is `grid[0...width-1][0...height-1]`

Comment: Arrays and vectors are very different things.

Answer (score 23):

You can also create a 2D array like this (using `Vec`) if you don't have a known size at compile time:

```
let width = 4;
let height = 4;

let mut array = vec![vec![0; width]; height];
```

Use it like this:

```
array[2][2] = 5;

println!("{:?}", array);
```

Output:

> 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0
>   0 0 5 0
>   0 0 0 0

Available since rust 1.0.0 https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html

Comment: This method has a problem: instead of idiomatic C arrays this code creates an array (Vec) of pointers (other Vec's) to different locations in the heap. It can cost you a significant performance loss on some array operations.

Comment: I disagree with totikom. I'm not a rust expert, but I'm fairly sure that Vec contains its contents directly, not via a pointer (unless you make a Vec<Box<T>>). So a Vec<Vec<T>> has some overhead (the size of the header of Vec), but for grid size NxM it only has N overhead, not NxM (and much better cache locality).

Comment: @mcherm from the aforementioned link to the official doc: "Vec is and always will be a (pointer, capacity, length) triplet." it has N overhead, but each row can still end in a completely different location on the heap.

Comment: Thanks much! How to make it a vec of `u64`s?

Comment: @Lori You can specify the type like this `let mut array: Vec<Vec<u64>> = ...`

Answer (score 14):

**Initialization:**
There are several approaches for 2D Array initialization:

1. Using constants for M (rows) & N (columns)

   ```
   const M: usize = 2;
   const N: usize = 4;

   let mut grid = [[0 as u8; N] ; M];
   ```
2. Explicit declaration with type annotations

   ```
   let mut grid: [[u8; 4]; 2] = [[0; 4]; 2];
   ```

**Traversing:**
The **read-only** traversing is as easy as:

```
for (i, row) in grid.iter().enumerate() {
    for (j, col) in row.iter().enumerate() {
        print!("{}", col);
    }
    println!()
}
```

or

```
for el in grid.iter().flat_map(|r| r.iter()) {
    println!("{}", el);
}
```

**Updating element(s):**

```
for (i, row) in grid.iter_mut().enumerate() {
    for (j, col) in row.iter_mut().enumerate() {
        col = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are open to installing a crate, the `ndarray` can gracefully do it for you.

```
use ndarray::Array2;
let mut array = Array2::zeros((4, 3));
array[[1, 1]] = 7;
```

With some of the already existing answers, it is not possible to create an array using non-constant dimensions. There is no such problems with `ndarray`. You can also effortlessly create dimensions of more than two dimensions.

You can find more details [here](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.0/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html) and [here](https://crates.io/crates/ndarray).

Answer (score 8):

With explicit initialization

```rust
let directions: [[i32; 2]; 4] = [[-1, 0], [0, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

With the same value

```rust
let directions: [[i32; 2]; 4] = [[0; 2]; 4];
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, the question of how to create a vector is properly addressed above. Here is the code snippet to create a two-dimensional vector and then fill it with user input:

```
use std::io;

fn main(){
    let width = 4;
    let height = 4;

    let mut array = vec![vec![0; width]; height];

    for i in 0..4 {
        let mut xstr = String::from("");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut xstr).ok().expect("read error");
        array[i] = xstr
            .split_whitespace()
            .map(|s| s.parse().expect("parse error"))
            .collect();
    }

    println!("{:?}", array)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Idiomatic C 2-dimensional arrays are declared using the same order of array sizes as used when accessing the array:

```c
// Declaration
int array_2d[8][16]; // An 8 by 16 2D array
...
// Access
array_2d[0][1] = 5;
```

In Rust, the declaration sizes are flipped; to create an 8 by 16 2-dimensional array, the syntax is:

```
// Declaration
let mut array_2d: [[i32; 16]; 8];
...
// Access (same as idiomatic C. types for added explicitness)
array_2d[0_usize][1_usize] = 5;
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of how would I pass such a 2D array to a function?

Answer (score 4):

Another example of a two-dimensional string array:

```rust
fn main() {
    let width = 2;
    let height = 3;

    let mut a: Vec<Vec<String>> = vec![vec![String::from(""); width]; height];

    for i in 0..height {
        for j in 0..width {
            let s = format!("{}:{}", i + 1, j + 1);
            a[i][j] = s;
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", a);
}
```

Output:

```
[
  ["1:1", "1:2"],
  ["2:1", "2:2"],
  ["3:1", "3:2"]
]
```

But I am not sure why we cannot use this form: `a = [[String::from(""), 2], 3]`. I don't understand the difference between `vec![]` and `[]`.

Comment: The last part looks like a follow-up question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vec! macro and specify the dimensions of the array like so:

```
let mut state = vec![[0; 4]; 4];
```

This creates a 4x4 array of u8 values with all elements initialized to 0.

Or you can use the arrayvec crate to create a fixed-size array like so:

```
use arrayvec::ArrayVec;

let mut state: ArrayVec<[[u8; 4]; 4]> = ArrayVec::new();
```

This creates an empty mutable 4x4 array of u8 values that can be resized up to a maximum of 4 elements.

Keep in mind that when creating a two-dimensional array in Rust, the innermost dimension should come first in the type, followed by the outer dimensions. So in the examples above, the type of state is Vec<[u8; 4]> or ArrayVec<[[u8; 4]; 4]>.

Answer (score 1):

with macro vec![]
..

```
let n = 18;
let mut grid = vec![vec![0; n]; n];

grid[0][0] = 1;
```